# Traefik Reverse Proxy with Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, traefik

I have docker compose with nginx running with the following config:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
     - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/rainloop
    ports:
     - "8081:80"

    labels:
     - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:www.example.com"
     - "traefik.port=8081"
```

and traefik in docker-compose with the following config:

```
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:alpine 
    command: --api --docker 

    ports:
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
      - "8080:8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - ./traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
```

the traefik.toml is kept basic and looks like this

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
```

The Web UI shows the following

[image]

When calling my domain www.example.com I get a timeout.

Comment: put both the traefik service and your 'web' service on the same network. Usually you will designate the network traefik is on as an external network in your own service's stack and assign the service you want to access through traefik to that network. Leave out supporting containers that traefik won't access (like a database or memcached, for example)

Comment: Could you give an example? The way I tried didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following in your traefik.toml

```
[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
watch = true
```

Create a network with `docker network create traefik-net`

Deploy traefik with

```
version: '3'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    command: --api
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8080:8080 # Port for the web UI
    networks:
      - traefik-net
```

Deploy nginx with

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    image: nginx
    networks:
    - traefik-net
    labels:
    - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-net"
    - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${DOMAIN}"
    - "traefik.backend=nginx"
    - "traefik.port=80" # you should use exposed port, not published
```

Comment: It's not neccessary to use the command "--docker" and should not be used, as you  can read here: https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/663#issuecomment-387490123 but that has nothing to do with the actual problem and I also had this in my question ;-). This answer solves the issue

Answer (score -1):

You need to put both container on same network.

1. Create a docker network inside your host machine. `docker network create {network name}`.
2. In your `docker-compose` use the existing network that you created to connect both containers. You can read https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network on how to use it.
3. Add each service to the above network.